# comparing Column on different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have Sheet1 with a variable number of account numbers in column A, I want to compare them with a variable number of account numbers in Sheet2 column A.

I want to collate the two columns together on sheet3 but not duplicate the account numbers.

So basically:

Sheet1:

```
A1 
a3334
a4455
a76655
```

Sheet2:

```
A1
a4455
a76655
a3024
a53525
```

then sheet3 would end up looking like:

Sheet3:

```
A1
a3334
a4455
a76655
a3024
a53525
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work. It combines the two columns from sheet1 and sheet2 into sheet 3, and then removes the duplicates.

```
Sub combineandcompare()
Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range

Set range1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
Set range2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

For Each x In range1
    For Each y In range2
             Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = x.Value
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = y.Value
    Next y
Next x

Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

End Sub
```